# How to get LOCALIZED character on keypress?

Tags: javascript, localization, dom-events, keypress, keyboard-layout

I need to get **localized character** on `keypress` event. For example: on a Czech keyboard I need to get ř not 5 character (key code 53) (see [Czech keyboard layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Keyboard_layout_Czech.svg)). Is there any other way to get character and to not use text input and reading value? By other words is there any way how to get character from event object respecting current user keyboard layout?

---

(Added sample code)

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
function onLoad() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("test"));
    document.getElementById("test").onkeydown = function(event) {
                console.log("Code: "+event.keyCode+"; Key: "+String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));
        }
}
</script>
<body onLoad="onLoad();">
    <input id="test">
</body>
</html>
```

(Example [online](http://projekty.mujserver.net/stackoverflow/questions-5420005-js-how-to-get-localized-character-on-keypress/example.html))

When you try this code, and you press <kbd>ř</kbd>-key  you will see in Firebug console "Code: 53; Key: 5". And I need to get "ř" not "5".

I think that this "problem" appears on all non-English keyboards.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the `keypress` event will give you the character typed, regardless of keyboard layout.

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    var charTyped = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    alert("Character typed: " + charTyped);
};
```

Here's my usual link to Jan Wolter's excellent page documenting JavaScript key handling: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your aswer. But I need to get **localized** character, character that is affected by keyboard layout.

Comment: @Honza: Unless I've fundamentally misunderstood, that is precisely what you'll get from my code. Your example uses `keydown`, which is the wrong event. Only the `keypress` event can give you reliable information about the character typed.

Comment: Oh, yes! **Keypress** is the solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: But what if you whant to know the é character was entered?

Comment: @jvacaq: `keypress` gives you that.

Comment: However, what if I'm typing German on an English keyboard and need to type a sequence of keypresses to get to the real character? E.g. A-umlaut (ä) is entered as Alt-U, followed by A on Mac OS. How can I get the umlaut character as a single character after the whole sequence is punched in?

Comment: I made a CodePen out of this for anybody who wants to see it in action:

https://codepen.io/obahareth/pen/eRBJBr

Answer (score 2):

And make sure you are using 'keypress', but not 'keydown' event.

If you use 'keydown' `String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode || event.which)`, it won't return you a localised character. At least this was an issue for me on OS X with Chrome / FF.