# JavaScript API to get localized key names for shortcuts

Tags: javascript, internationalization, keyboard-events

I have a web page listening to certain key combinations, and want to show these shortcuts to the user. Is there API which will give me localized names for keys? I've seen [js: how to get LOCALIZED character on keypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420005/js-how-to-get-localized-character-on-keypress), but this doesn't help with e.g. arrow keys or modifier keys.

The page is actually in a Chrome/Firefox extension, so code which needs access to their APIs would be acceptable, but I don't see anything in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/commands or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/i18n.